# VBA guidance for conditional copy and paste/data transfer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with two worksheets; Input and Database. What I am trying to do is have the data from Input transfer to Database. The caveat however, is if cell B4 in Input shows "Initial", I want the data to be added to a new row in a formatted table in Database. Alternatively, if cell B4 in Input shows "Repeat 1", I want the data to be appended to the same row as this individual's previous data set, as indicated by the ID number in cell B3 in Input. I have been able to get the first part to work with some help (if cell B4 in Input shows "Initial"), however I can't get the "Repeat 1" part to work. The code I have up until now is:

```
Sub test()

Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Dim databaseWks As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim newRow As Range

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set databaseWks = Worksheets("Database")
Set tbl = databaseWks.ListObjects("Table1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If inputWks.Range("B4").Value = "Initial" Then

    Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add.Range

    With newRow

        .Range("A1").Value = inputWks.Range("B3").Value
        .Range("B1").Value = inputWks.Range("B4").Value
        .Range("S1").Value = inputWks.Range("B2").Value
        .Range("C1").Value = inputWks.Range("B5").Value
        .Range("D1").Value = inputWks.Range("B6").Value
        .Range("F1").Value = inputWks.Range("B7").Value
        .Range("G1").Value = inputWks.Range("B8").Value
        .Range("I1").Value = inputWks.Range("B9").Value
        .Range("J1").Value = inputWks.Range("B10").Value
        .Range("K1").Value = inputWks.Range("B11").Value
        .Range("L1").Value = inputWks.Range("B12").Value

    End With

ElseIf inputWks.Range("B4").Value = "Repeat 1" Then

    fu_row = databaseWks.Range("A:A").Find(What:=inputWks.Range("B3"), LookIn:=xlValues).Row

        fu_row.Range("EY").Value = inputWks.Range("B2").Value
        fu_row.Range("FA").Value = inputWks.Range("B4").Value
        fu_row.Range("FB").Value = inputWks.Range("B7").Value
        fu_row.Range("FC").Value = inputWks.Range("B8").Value
        fu_row.Range("FD").Value = inputWks.Range("B12").Value

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The reason why the amount of data transferring is different is just due to some info not being required at follow-up visits. Also, I am aware of the Forms function in Excel, however our dataset will be more than 32 items, which is the limit of Forms from what I have read.

Hope someone is able to provide some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Please read the description of tags before choosing them. In this case, the excel-vba tag you added starts with **THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL. PLEASE DO NOT ADD IT TO NEW QUESTIONS**. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to put something in column EY of the row found you need `cells(fu_row,"EY").Value=...`, remembering to include sheet reference.